# Spark: Can not build a HashedRelation that is larger than 8G

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently encountering this exception in Spark 2.3, while running in Azure HDInsight 3.6 on an 80 node cluster:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not build a HashedRelation that is larger than 8G
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.LongToUnsafeRowMap.grow(HashedRelation.scala:623)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.LongToUnsafeRowMap.append(HashedRelation.scala:570)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.LongHashedRelation$.apply(HashedRelation.scala:867)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashedRelation$.apply(HashedRelation.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoinExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$joins$ShuffledHashJoinExec$$buildHashedRelation(ShuffledHashJoinExec.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffledHashJoinExec.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffledHashJoinExec.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This has occurred multiple times while performing a union between 6 tables, one of which is several GB. However, it does not always occur and I cannot reproduce it. This union has run on a much larger dataframe on the same size and number of executors without failing. It happened on a particular run for all 5 retries, and after setting "spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin" to true, it then ran through. Now when trying to reproduce it on a new cluster, with everything else being the same, I cannot, and it runs as expected.

Are there any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: do you use broadcast() explicitly on any of the tables? explicit broadcast() has a hard limit at 8GB so it might be the root cause.

Comment: No. I am not using any explicit broadcasts. The 6 tables are already cached in memory too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was able to resolve this, here is what I found:
It was discovered that one of the dataframes in the union was not cached, and was causing this issue. This dataframe had a large number of partitions, but had 0 rows.

This was difficult to discover as it was unexpected. I don't have a link, but there is a known issue of extreme performance degradation of having a multi-partition dataframe with 0 rows.